# how to use @react-native-community/datetimepicker for setting time

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How can I use `@react-native-community/datetimepicker` to set time? I'm searching for it but can't find any answers can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to set the mode

```
<RNDateTimePicker mode="time" />
```

From the docs

> mode (optional)
> Defines the type of the picker.
>
> List of possible values:
>
> ```
> "date" (default for iOS and Android and Windows)
> "time"
> "datetime" (iOS only)
> "countdown" (iOS only)
> ```

You can refer the docs here

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/datetimepicker#mode-optional